# Adding additional dots / full stops / periods causes duplicate URLs

Tags: php, wordpress, sanitization

A website has linked to my site incorrectly, adding a full stop at the end of the link:

```
http://www.example.com/hello-world.
```

I would have expected this to go to a 404 page, instead, it loads the correct page, without redirecting to the valid URL.

This will be creating duplicate content issues in search engines.

Looking at a few other Wordpress site, it seems that it's a common issue, if you enter any number of full stops or hyphens (just the couple I came across), the page loads the correct content:

```
http://www.example.com/hello-------world.......
http://www.example.com/hello-....world-----
```

Has anyone else come across this issue and found a solution?

I could setup a redirect from the linked URL to the correct URL, but ideally I'd like to find a solution so this won't occur in the future.

**UPDATE**

I've found that the issue seems to be due to the `sanitize_title_with_dashes` function in **/wp-includes/formatting.php (line 954)**:

```
function sanitize_title_with_dashes($title, $raw_title = '', $context = 'display') {

    echo "1: " . $title . "<br />";

    $title = strip_tags($title);
    // Preserve escaped octets.
    $title = preg_replace('|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '---$1---', $title);
    // Remove percent signs that are not part of an octet.
    $title = str_replace('%', '', $title);
    // Restore octets.
    $title = preg_replace('|---([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])---|', '%$1', $title);

    if (seems_utf8($title)) {
        if (function_exists('mb_strtolower')) {
            $title = mb_strtolower($title, 'UTF-8');
        }
        $title = utf8_uri_encode($title, 200);
    }

    $title = strtolower($title);
    $title = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $title); // kill entities
    $title = str_replace('.', '-', $title);

    echo "2: " . $title . "<br />";

    if ( 'save' == $context ) {
        // Convert nbsp, ndash and mdash to hyphens
        $title = str_replace( array( '%c2%a0', '%e2%80%93', '%e2%80%94' ), '-', $title );

        // Strip these characters entirely
        $title = str_replace( array(
            // iexcl and iquest
            '%c2%a1', '%c2%bf',
            // angle quotes
            '%c2%ab', '%c2%bb', '%e2%80%b9', '%e2%80%ba',
            // curly quotes
            '%e2%80%98', '%e2%80%99', '%e2%80%9c', '%e2%80%9d',
            '%e2%80%9a', '%e2%80%9b', '%e2%80%9e', '%e2%80%9f',
            // copy, reg, deg, hellip and trade
            '%c2%a9', '%c2%ae', '%c2%b0', '%e2%80%a6', '%e2%84%a2',
        ), '', $title );

        // Convert times to x
        $title = str_replace( '%c3%97', 'x', $title );
    }

    $title = preg_replace('/[^%a-z0-9 _-]/', '', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $title);
    $title = trim($title, '-');

    return $title;
}
```

It seems to be replacing full stops with hyphens, then replacing multiple hyphens, then trimming hyphens from the end of the URL.

**UPDATE**

It doesn't seem that this is an issue with categories, I wonder why the page/post titles are sanitized to that level when categories aren't...

Answer (score 0):

That because of the way the url rewriting is rewritten.

You may want to mess with it to fix the problem. It can be found in the `.htaccess` file, at the website's document root.

Answer (score 0):

A search engine won't index any of those links unless you or somebody else has deliberately linked to them. Basically, I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Cause:

When taking in a URL slug, WordPress probably sanitizes the variable and strips out unwanted characters. I doubt it has anything to do with the actual .htaccess file.